# Using std::vector emplace_back() with std::pair with constructor initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization

```
vector<pair<ofVec3f, ofVec3f>> Geometry;

// where ofVec3f is a class with a constructor w/ an initializer list
// inline ofVec3f::ofVec3f( float _x, float _y, float _z ):x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}

Geometry.emplace_back((1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f), (4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f));
```

I'm trying to put in some values in my vector without having to create a temporary std::pair of ofVec3f

This code compiles in Visual Studio 2017.  However the above code when executed assigns values Geometry[0].first = {3.0, 3.0, 3.0} and second = {6.0, 6.0, 6.0}

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the piecewise constructor, which is great to keep the rules of move semantics (more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct))

```
Geometry.emplace_back(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f), std::forward_as_tuple(4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this without using `std::piecewise_construct` and `std::forward_as_tuple` as @Ruan's answer points out, this is because `(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f)` and `(4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f)` are seen as independent expressions. Both expressions are evaluated using 2 comma operators which basically just returns the right side expression. This gives you `(3.0f)` and `(6.0f)`, that's where your values come from.